# pip install psycopg2 error

Tags: python, windows, psycopg2

I try to use pip install psycopg2 on windows10 and python3.5, but it show me below error message. how can i fix it ?

> Command
>   "d:\desktop\learn\python\webcatch\appserver\webcatch\scripts\python.exe
>   -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\16022001\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-rsorislh\psycopg2\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record
>   C:\Users\16022001\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-kzsbvzx9-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers d:\desktop\learn\python\webcatch\appserver\webcatch\include\site\python3.5\psycopg2"
>   failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\16022001\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-rsorislh\psycopg2\

Comment: You need to download the Windows binary from http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/. The package has some system dependencies so `pip install` likely won't work.

Comment: i try to use it before, but when i try to import , it show me the message  **ImportError: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'**

Comment: Did you install the right package (x86 vs x64)? Either way, if you don't mind switching to a different python distribution, use Anaconda https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs which is much easier to manage and install packages on windows.

Comment: i am sure that i install right package(64bits), and Anaconda seems not supply psycopg2 for windows

Comment: well..........you are right, i think my python is 64bits as my computer . But it  seems not true. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`pip install psycopg` this worked for me, don't mention version i.e (pip install psycopg2)